# How to move marker smoothly without blinking in map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have problem in my markers every time I get request to our server to get the newly location of my devices and updated the position of my markers on the map,when my vehicle devices move,the marker will jump to the newly location and its flickering.
How can I avoid this not to flickering,or my Marker can move smoothly.

Thank you in advance.

```
var map;
var marker;
var markerarray =[];

setInterval(function(){

    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "vehiclecordinates.php",
        success: function(data){

            coordinates = data.latlng;
            vehiclename = data.vehiclename;

            for (var i = 0; i < coordinates.length; i++) {

                newcoordinate = new google.maps.LatLng(coordinates[i].split(",")[0],coordinates[i].split(",")[1]);
                marker =  new MarkerWithLabel({
                     map:map,
                     labelClass: "mylabels",
                     labelStyle: {opacity: 1.0},
                     labelContent: '<div>'+ vehiclename[i]+'</div>',
                     icon:{
                         //some options here
                     },
                });

                marker.setPosition(newcoordinate);
                markerarray.push(marker);
            }
        }
    });

    setTimeout(function () {
        removeMarkers();
        delete marker;
    }, 1000);
},5000);

function removeMarkers() {
    for(var i = 0; i < markerarray.length; i++) {
        markerarray[i].setMap(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you don't want them to flicker, don't "remove" them from the map, update their position.

Comment: but if I will not remove the marker my browser will hang,.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't want them to flicker, don't "remove" them from the map, update their position.

```
var map;
var marker;
var markerarray =[];

setInterval(function(){
  $.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "vehiclecordinates.php",
    success: function(data){
      coordinates = data.latlng;
      vehiclename = data.vehiclename;
      for (var i = 0; i < coordinates.length; i++) {
        newcoordinate = new google.maps.LatLng(coordinates[i].split(",")[0],coordinates[i].split(",")[1]);
        if (markerarray[vehiclename[i]] && markerarray[vehiclename[i]].setPosition){
          markerarray[vehiclename[i]].setPosition(newcoordinate);
        else {
          marker =  new MarkerWithLabel({
            map:map,
            labelClass: "mylabels",
            labelStyle: {opacity: 1.0},
            labelContent: '<div>'+ vehiclename[i]+'</div>',
            icon:{
              //some options here
            }
          });
          marker.setPosition(newcoordinate);
          markerarray[vehiclename[i]] = marker;
        }
      }
    }
  });
},5000);
```

See [example](http://jsfiddle.net/hvvf8dhk/2/) based off the example in [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25490252/howto-dynamically-update-markers-from-json-on-google-maps/25493090#25493090)

Comment: I see,Okay I will try this solution and I will let you know.I'll be back.Thank you for this and for the quick reply.

Comment: Note that this code is untested (you didn't provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with enough information to allow that), might need debugging.

Comment: okay,I will just try and i will try to debug if I can.by the way is it possible to make my marker will move like this example http://econym.org.uk/gmap/example_cartrip.htm eventhough I have devices that will send coordinates.?

Comment: You probably need to choose what you want.  That example has the whole path and moves the marker along it in small increments. You have "real" data, I assume you want to show the current position.  If you want you can write code to move each marker some fraction of the distance to its new position at a faster rate; but if you have lots of markers that is going to take a lot more processing power.