# how to update location without refresh google map using javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am developing an application that is to make real-time tracking of a  vehicles.

I'm at the end of this application but I have a problem. I can not update my markers without reloading map
I tried with settimeout() ..but reload the map

here is my code thank you for your help.

```
  function loadMap() {
            var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
            var ab = contactsName;
            var bc = contactsNumber;
            queryObject.find({
                success: function(results) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                        contactsName = results[i].get("lat");
                        contactsNumber = results[i].get("long");
                    }
                },
                error: function(error) {
                    alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
                }
            });
            var mapOptions = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(ab, bc),
                zoom: 16
            }
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("sample"), mapOptions);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(ab, bc),
                map: map,
                draggable: true,
                icon: 'http://findicons.com/files/icons/1496/world_of_copland_2/32/school_bus.png',
            });
            setTimeout(function() {
                loadMap();
            }, 10000);

        }
```

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference
setPosition()

Comment: possible duplicate of [howto: dynamically update markers from JSON on google maps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25490252/howto-dynamically-update-markers-from-json-on-google-maps)

Answer (score 0):

To change marker location, make sure it is global or stored as class property and then you can update its position with something like

```
marker.setPosition(nweLocation);
```

See [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker) for more info